# DRF ManytoMany filtering on related model, in subquery?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

There are two models, a Page model and a Banner model, which are manyToMany related.
The parameters API is twitched, which returns a list of pages and banners for each page. The Banner model has a field is_show by which you need to additionally filter the list of banners, i.e. in the admin panel, the banner can be selected for the model, but if is_show = False, then you do not need to return it to the API.

## views

```
class PagesListView(generics.ListAPIView,
                   viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Page.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PageSerializer
```

## models

```
class Banner(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Заголовок', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    is_show = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Управление отображением', null=False)
    pages = models.ManyToManyField(
        Page, blank=True, related_name='banners')

class Page(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

## serializers

```
class BannerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Banner
        fields = '__all__'


class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     banners = BannerSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

     class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields = '__all__'
```

The question is how to filter Banner by is_show field?

If you just override the queryset for the view like this:

```
queryset = Page.objects.filters(banners__is_show=True)
```

then this is not the desired behavior. In this way, I am filtering the Page list, and I need to "wedge" into filtering the Banner list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `related_name` with [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects)

For ex:

```
queryset = Page.objects.all().prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('banners', queryset=Banner.objects.filter(is_show=True)))
```